# How to have a custom timestamp and a hash sha256 and convert them into a string with Rust?

Tags: hash, rust, type-conversion, timestamp, sha256

I try to have a custom timestamp like this : YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
I use this to have my current time :

```
let timestamp = chrono::offset::Local::now();
```

to obtain somethings like :

```
2020-11-12T09:53:02.419182341+00:00
```

So how can I extract/convert this into the format I want, and after to convert it into a string?
Because I want to concatenate it with a hash.
I'm actually using this :

```
let auth = [timestamp, hash].concat();
```

And I have a other problem :
how to encode my hash in sha256 and how to convert it into a string ?
Because I'm actually using :

```
  let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
  hasher.update("Hello world");
  let hash = hasher.finalize();
  println!("{:?}", hash);
```

And I obtain something like :

```
[100, 236, 136, 202, 0, 178, 104, 229, 186, 26, 53, 103, 138, 27, 83, 22, 210, 18, 244, 243, 102, 178, 71, 114, 50, 83, 74, 138, 236, 163, 127, 60]
```

Is it right?

I've tried to use elastic_types, format, SystemTime, ...
But I can't reach my goal ...
So your help would be welcome ! :)

Comment: "How can I extract/convert this into the format I want and convert it into a string?" What is the time format that you're after? An example would help.

Comment: We are trying to build a library of questions useful to future readers on StackOverflow. To this end, it would be useful if you could ask unrelated questions separately.

Comment: For the format I write it on the top : YYYYMMDDHHMMSS like : 20201112123030

Comment: My two questions are not unrelated because I have to work with the both to obtain the result, but I well understand what you say and I will do it if it's inescapable

Comment: You ask how to format a timestamp in a certain format, and then how to format a SHA256 as a string. I understand that you want to concatenate the two strings, but that doesn't change anything about how these questions are answered individually.

Comment: I don't think it's a serious problem, that's why I asking only one question, I only have one big problem and 2 small problems, so I didn't think to do 2 subjects,but you're right, yes I will do it in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I convert this into the format I want and convert it into a `String`?

Chrono has a wide range of formatting options in [`chrono::format::strftime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/format/strftime/index.html), e.g:

```rust
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", Local::now().format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")); // YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
}
```

```sh
202011121108
```

> How do I encode my hash in `Sha256` and how do I convert it to a `String`?

Using `{:?}` will give you the result as implemented by the `Debug` trait.

It seems you're after the hexadecimal string for which you could use `{:x}` or `{:X}` for lower- and uppercase hexadecimal, e.g:

```rust
use sha2::{Sha256, Digest};

fn main() {
    println!("{:x}", Sha256::digest(b"Hello world"));
}
```

```sh
64ec88ca00b268e5ba1a35678a1b5316d212f4f366b2477232534a8aeca37f3c
```

There's more on this in the Rust docs for [`std::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/).

---

To concatenate both, you could then do something akin to the following:

```rust
use chrono::prelude::*;
use sha2::{Sha256, Digest};

fn main() {
    let s = "Hello world";

    println!("{}{:x}",
        Local::now().format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),
        Sha256::digest(s.as_bytes())
    );
}
```

```sh
2020111211080464ec88ca00b268e5ba1a35678a1b5316d212f4f366b2477232534a8aeca37f3c
```

Comment: oh thank you so much ! You help me a lot, to do and understands several things !
Now I just need to solve this : expected struct `std::string::String`, found struct `sha2::digest::generic_array::GenericArray` concerning the hash because I want to concatenate it with a string and store this into a variable, so I can't use a println. Anyway, thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem. If you want to create a `String` you can use [`format!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html) instead.

Have a great day.

Comment: I'm a newbie, so my questions can be obvious but it help me much !
Yes I try to use format!() but it doesn't work with this struct : cannot be formatted with the default formatter
Have a great day too !